# Statically compile a C++ app with GCC into a binary

Tags: c++, windows, unix, gcc, compiler-construction

How do I statically compile an app with GCC on a Ubuntu machine targeting unix? And how would I target 32-bit/64-bit machines and machines with different versions of GLIBC or whatever a unix C++ app is typically dependent on? I want to then distribute this app in binary form and run it on a unix machine without needing to compile from source.

Similarly, can I [compile this app on Windows such that it will run on unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579695/how-do-i-cross-compile-c-code-on-windows-for-a-binary-to-also-be-run-on-unix-so?rq=1)?

Comment: You cannot "target Unix" in general. If you build a Linux binary, it will run only on Linux systems. FreeBSD has a Linux compatibility layer, but that's the only exception. The binary will not run on Mac OS X, nor Solaris, nor on other Unix systems.

Comment: If you want to proof yourself from different verisons of the clib and standard library on different unix machines  u want the flags -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++. This embeds them in the file so you are not dependent of the .so files on the system where it will run

Comment: @Rolle - Can you please add your comment as an answer? Its very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can create statically compiled 32-bit only executable, which should work on any known Linux without complaining for missing libs:

```
g++ -m32 -static -o myprog myprog.cpp
```

One downside to this is that minimum size for executable will be at least 600 KB.

Note: if you are getting compilation errors, be sure to have package `g++-multilib` installed.

Answer (score 3):

To compile it so it will run on Linux just compile it like so:

```
g++ -o myapp myapp-a.cop myappb.cop -L mylib1
```

This should work on most versions of Linux, and some versions of FreeBSD too.

This does not statically link against libstdc++, but this is maybe a better way to go. as a rule of thumb you should dynamically link against the OS c lib to allow your app to work even if the syscall abi changes.

You can force a 32 bit compile from a 64 bit machine with '-m32' as one off your flags. It sets the compilation mode to 32 bit.

As for  compiling on Windows: yes. you can do it. it is called *cross compiling*. You first need to compile a toolchain that will target Linux.

Comment: Unfortunately, this recipe will NOT work on systems which use different versions of glibc or libstdc++ (like older Linux systems) because you do not use static compilation.