# How to bundle perl libraries with my cross platform script?

Tags: perl, dependencies, debian, cross-platform, solaris

I developped a script in Perl that uses 2 extra libraries, [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-1.37/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm) and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm), which I installed easily using `CPAN` on my Debian laptop.

Ultimatly, my goal is to deploy this script on a solaris server. However, this server is not connected to internet and thus cannot auto install missing dependencies.

So far, I tried using [PP](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.018/lib/pp.pm), which allowed me to run this script on another Ubuntu computer without needing to install manually the extra libraries, but returned an error : `Cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on Solaris.

As I suspected this was due to the differences between both architectures, I packed my script with a `./lib` folder containing all dependencies (the `./lib` was obtained by doing `pp -B -p -o script.par myscript.pl` and extracting the resulting `./lib` folder).

Following the leads I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570762/how-can-i-create-a-portable-perl-when-i-cant-install-modules-on-the-target-host), I tried with `use lib "./lib` and with `BEGIN { unshift @INC, "lib"; }` at the start of my script, but I got an error saying I didn't include my libraries when I ran it.

Is there a way to port those libraries ? Is there another approach ?

Comment: Make `pp` on your own Solaris which is 'internet enabled'? `:)`

Comment: I don't have one :) Otherwise I would just develop my script on it (the solaris server is from my company, it can only comunicate with other machines on the local network)

Comment: You can install Solaris in a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox) and use it for development. Installing Net::SSH::Perl in Solaris may be quite hard, though. You may like to investigate other Perl SSH packages as Net::SSH2, Net::OpenSSH and Net::SSH::Any.

Comment: Can your Solaris box connect to another server in your network which has Internet access?  If so, then setup a local cpan mirror on that system and point to that mirror when installing modules on the Solaris box.

Comment: @salva Thanks for the insight. I'll try those libraries at home, and give a feedback once I try it. Is there a specific reason as to why `Net::SSH::Perl` doesn't work well on Solaris? I'm just a bit frustrated there isn't a simple way to port existing libraries without cpan...

Comment: @RonBergin No, the network is local only. Furtherrmore, I have to take my computer home when I want to work with cpan as nertworking actions are blocked by the company proxy if not executed throug a web browser.

Comment: cpan can happily work across a proxy! You can configure it at the CPAN shell or just setting the environment variable `http_proxy=http://...`. Another alternative is to use [CPAN::Mini](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini) to build a local mirror of CPAN.

Comment: @salva when I said proxy, it was a euphemism :) My computer is heavily locked when I connect to my work network (no admin rights, limited connectivity, control panel locked, vpn with no access to config, ...), a bit less when I take it home. I'll try it there and update with feedback later.

Comment: Well, can you run VirtualBox? can you install CPAN::Mini? that would make your life happier... otherwise look for a better job in a place where people is empowered to actually get things done, really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl) relies upon several XS modules, such as [`Math::GMP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::GMP), [`Math::Pari`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Pari) and others.  There's no way around actually compiling them (as in compiling them with C, not Perl) on the Solaris box.

You will also need the underlying C libraries (i.e. libgmp, libpari).  The `Math::Pari` build script will download its library, but you've indicated that's not possible on your target Solaris box.

[`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) can help you download the Perl dependencies in preparation for moving them to your target machine and build them on it.

If you have proper dependency entries in your project's `Makefile.PL` or `cpanfile`, running

```
cpanm --installdeps  -L deps --save-dists dists .
```

on your devel machine in your project directory (note the trailing dot) will download all of its dependencies into the `dists` directory.

You can then copy that directory to your target Solaris box (along with `cpanm`) and pass it to `cpanm` using its  `--mirror` option.

For example, I just did this for `Net::SSH::Perl`'s dependencies:

```
cpanm --installdeps -L deps --save-dists dists Net::SSH::Perl
```

It downloaded and installed 34 distributions into `deps`, saving the archives in `dists`.

I can build `Net::SSH::Perl` using the downloaded distributions via:

```
cpanm --mirror file://${PWD}/dists  Net::SSH::Perl
```

Note that while `cpanm` is handy, you don't actually need it to install the required modules. You can manually install them (in the correct order) by unpacking them and then running

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make install
```

or

```
perl Build.PL
./Build
./Build install
```

as appropriate for the specific module